# Do chains on single-speed last longer than those on geared bikes?

Tags: chain, single-speed

I have a Jamis Beatnik (love) and ride on the single-speed side of my hub.  I'm wondering - derailleurs seem to me like they might 'stress' the chain (even if only slightly) more than single-speed in the process of changing gears.  Are geared bikes' chains harder to maintain / shorter lived than single-speeds'?

(Background: I noticed I hardly have to clean my chain on my single speed, and it always looks great and feels tight.)

Comment: Sounds like you're not riding very hard. Single speed chains stretch like crazy; I need to replace mine at least annually.

Comment: Not sure about that.  I do about 20 miles a week of mostly inner-city and suburban commuting, am 225 lbs, and have had the same chain for two years. By bike mechanic usually jokes how hard I seem to ride the frame (replaced my crankset, heavy duty tubes, big, flat bmx pedals).  I've wiped the chain down once, but never "cleaned" or oiled it, and with a few very small exceptions it looks almost new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single speed last longer and cost less.  More metal and less (no) flex.

SS comes in 1/8 and 3/32. 
I would contend a SS 3/32 of the same basic construction is stronger than a 3/32 7 speed because it does not need to be built to flex and it is not flexed.

I am not finding any pictures of 3/32 SS chains and the chain on my SS bike is 1/8.
So I guess it is not really a straight comparison.
But a SS will take a 1/8 and geared will not so it is a fair comparison.

Also SS is built to take the abuse of a fixie.  In a fixie the chain has to take the braking force and gets hammered.  Note the question is SS not fixie.

Comment: Are you sure the result here is true? Obviously this is anecdotal, but I've gone through _many_ more chains on my fixie. I always assumed that you put tension on the chain because you have to keep peddling with the same gear when if you had a gear, you would have changed long ago.

Comment: @Niall But the question is SS not fixie.  Way different.

Comment: In my experience as bicycle mechanic, SS chains will last at least twice as long, but mostly even much longer. It is because they are less flexible (= stronger) and because they don't move from gear to gear during use. And mostly, SS chains are thicker to.